# Canopy Express in Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit doesn't start

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, permissions, python, canopy

I installed the 32-bit version of Canopy  Express in my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit machine. I followed the installation guides [here](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_linux.html). Then when I run the program I get the following dialogue:

```
Permission denied. Please change the permissions and restart Canopy.
```

I tried to run the program using `sudo`, but it didn't work.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: could you add the output of `strace -o /tmp/e -s 512 /path/to/canopy` to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Braiam. Following the output:

`strace: /path/to/canopy: command not found`